# Possible to change Swift keywords true and false to yes and no?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to change the keywords from true and false to yes and no, behind the scenes. I know I can just declare let yes = true and use the variable yes, but I would like the color of these keywords to be the same as the true and false keywords.

Comment: AFAIK, no, not without recompiling your own custom fork of the compiler (and then constantly updating that fork every time the main trunk is updated). Not even close to being worth it IMO.

Comment: There may be an Xcode editor/compiler setting (or you could create an Xcode extension) but the *real* issue is that the Swift language *is* `true/false` where Obj-C *is* `YES/NO`. Because of that, you'd have to go pretty deep into the editor/compiler.

Comment: I mentioned Xcode extension - here's a link to help you if you decide you'd like to try: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-xcode-source-editor-extension--cms-26772

Comment: Sure, it can be done using the methods others have talked about. However, it's a bunch of work for a trivial and confusing change. If you ever have to code with someone else then your changes will make the code a lot less readable and friendly. It's probably not worth the effort.